# In vue, how do i display attribute of tag? (how does v-for work with html?)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<ul>
    <span class="tabs"
         :class="{ activeTab: selectedTab === tab }"
          v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
          @click="selectedTab = tab"
          :key="tab">
          {{ index+1 }}. {{ tab }}</span>
</ul>

.....

 data() {
      return {
        tabs: ['Reviews', 'Make a Review'],
        selectedTab: 'Reviews'
        
      }
    }
  })
```

I want to know value of "tab" before click 'Reviews' or 'Make a Review'. so how do I display "tab"?

Comment: You already access `tab` within you loop `v-for`. Move `:class` after `v-for`

Comment: When a answer help you fix your issue, it's nice practice in StackOverflow community to 'reward' user who made it by clicking on gray tick to accept answer (between up/down arrows for voting).

Comment: To explain my thought, first ```tab``` is from ```v-for```. then i don't know if value of ```tab``` is ```Reviews``` or ```Make a Review```. but when i click ```Reviews``` or ```Make a Review```, word that i clicked insert to ```selectedTab```. Is ```tab``` assiged word that i clicked? if it is right why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `:class` after `v-for`

```
<ul>
    <span class="tabs"
        v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
        :class="{ activeTab: selected === tab }"
        @click="selectedTab = tab" 
        :key="tab">
        {{ index+1 }}. {{ tab }}</span>
</ul>
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. but my problem is not that. as i explain better, after v-for works what is value of 'tab'? and when i click 'Reviews' or 'Make a Review' i don't know what value of 'tab' is. i want to see value of  'tab' which is in v-for at vue devtools. if not possible, other method is ok. i just want to display value of 'tab' (not 'tabs')

Comment: sorry.. because  i don't know what i don't know. my question is unappropriate. although your answer is not what i want, thank you for your effort.^ㅡ^

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I found it!! i didn't know that `v-for` makes two html tag. so span tag of Reviews have this code.

```
:class="{ activeTab: selected === tab }"
@click="selectedTab = tab"
```

and span tag of Make a Review do too.

Comment: Nice! Congrats and happy coding :-)